# Why didn't the treatment for Lycanthropy work?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wolfman

In *The Wolfman (2010) UNRATED*, the asylum doctor tried treatment for **Lycanthropy** very well on Larry Talbot.

[image]

But again he transformed into a wolf at full moon, kills some doctors and escapes from the place. Why didn't the treatment for Lycanthropy work?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is here.

Comment: If the question here is 'What was the doctor trying to cure and why did it fail?' The answer to that is the Doctor diagnosed Lawrence with schizophrenia, the methods he used to 'cure' Lawrence (as seen in your image) were common in the 1940's. Despite constant warnings from Lawrence, the doctor didn't believe Lawrence when he said he would turn and kill every single one of them, the doctor simply believed his warnings where the rantings of a lunatic.

Comment: Just for more clarification: Lycanthropy is the scientific term for someone who has the werewolf curse. Lycanthropy is not a form of treatment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doctors believed his lycanthropy to be a mental delusion or disease where he just thought he was a wolf or werewolf. It is a real psychological disorder. They are using barbaric but societally acceptable at the time psychiatric methods to try to cure those delusions.

But he's a real werewolf and things like that don't work on real werewolves. Evidently.

The doctors did not think he could actually change into a wolf. They thought he was just Cray Cray.